# Node.js: reading a picture which is being overwritten, references the initial image only

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, sharp

I'm basically overwriting overwriteME.jpg inside

```
const screenshotDesktop = require('screenshot-desktop')
const sharp = require('sharp');

(async () => {

      while (1 < 5){
        var currentShot = screenshotDesktop.all()
        .then(imgs => {
            return  fs.writeFile(`/Users/ga/proj/overwriteME.jpg`, imgs[0], (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    crop();
            });
        });
         await delay(1000);

       }
   async function crop(crop){

       // original size from metadata
       var resizedImage = await sharp('/Users/ga/proj/overwriteME.jpg');
       var metadata = await resizedImage.metadata();
       console.log(metadata);
   };

})();


function delay(timeout) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
  });
}
```

I expected different metadata, as I'm taking screenshots of a video playing on the screen and overwriting overwriteME.jpg, and using Sharp to extract metadata.

What actually happened was the same metadata was being returned, when I thought sharp would reflect the file changes.

Somehow the file is changing, but when sharp reads it, it's referencing the same old picture from way in the beginning.

Comment: That is probably because `sharp` caches the file, try calling `sharp.cache(false)` to prevent that.

Comment: before or after loading the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a race condition mixing raw Promises without `await` and `await`-ing. Try to replace `= screenshotDesktop.all()` with `= await screenshotDesktop.all()`. You can also streamline the code using `await` exclusively (not sure what `while (1 < 5)` means, by the way):

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs').promises;

const screenshotDesktop = require('screenshot-desktop');
const sharp = require('sharp');

(async () => {
  while (1 < 5) {
    const imgs = await screenshotDesktop.all();
    await fs.writeFile('/Users/ga/proj/overwriteME.jpg', imgs[0]);
    await crop();
  }
})();

async function crop() {
  const resizedImage = await sharp('/Users/ga/proj/overwriteME.jpg');
  const metadata = await resizedImage.metadata();
  console.log(metadata);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to comments from @titus, `sharp.cache(false)` set right after the import statement worked for me.